# Redefining default_scope in concern (in Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, activesupport-concern

I'd like to redefine `default_scope` in model concern, but I'm getting this:

`You tried to define a scope named "default_scope" on the model "Product", but Active Record already defined a class method with the same name.`

```
module SoftDeletable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :default_scope, -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }
  end
end
```

Yes, I know there are gems for this, but the question is not about that.
Do you have an idea how can I set the `default_scope` in concern?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't really related to defining the scope as part of a concern. You'd see the same error if trying to define a scope called `default_scope` from within the model itself.

To set the default scope use [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope):

```
default_scope { where(deleted_at: nil) }
```

`scope` is for creating a named scope of your own, for example:

```
scope :non_deleted, -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }
```

would allow you to write

```
`Model.non_deleted.where....`
```

so the code in your question is trying to create a scope called `default_scope`, but as the error message suggests that scope `Model.default_scope...` would then conflict with the existing `default_scope` method that is used to *set* the default scope.

Comment: Ok, so what is the difference between `scope :default_scope, -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }` and `default_scope { where(deleted_at: nil) }`? The first is defining a new scope the second is overriding existing one?

Comment: added some more details